# How do you add a theme to PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, filezilla

I've recently installed PhpMyAdmin on the web server I'm currently hosting with DigitalOcean. I'm using Apache and Ubuntu 16.04 with this, and I can't seem to find the PhpMyAdmin folder for themes. Is there a way to install themes in Ubuntu's PhpMyAdmin?
Also, does anyone know how to search through a whole directory with FileZilla?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you're using distribution packages, putting the theme into `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/` will work.

Update: Please note that theme is always compatible only with subset of phpMyAdmin versions (usually only one major release, so for example with 4.7.x). Other themes will not work.

Comment: Thanks, but I've ran into a problem. I've uploaded the theme into FileZilla, and it appears in the dropdown menu, but when I click it the whole window doesn't appear. Here's what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/2f1mgvv.png (that's the full window). I even got the notice that all files successfully transferred. Do you know the issue?

Comment: In case this helps anyone reading this in the future: Make sure the installed theme is compatible with your phpMyAdmin version. The `metro` theme in the OPs screenshot for example has multiple different versions, each matching a specific phpMyAdmin version. Using an incompatible version can cause view issues.